# Pandas - loc setting column to true even though there is no match?

Tags: python, pandas

The row

```
Entry1                               1
Entry2                               0
Entry                                Y
```

The `Entry` I have defined as:

```
df.loc[(df['Entry1']==1) & (df['Entry2']==1),'Entry'] = 'Y'
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does your entire dataframe structure look like.  add df.info() to this question.